# Передача списка в шаблон

Tags: python, django, шаблоны

view

```
for ndir,b,fname in os.walk('C:/Users/user/AppData'):

        for name in fname:
            if len(name)!=0:
                if name[-4:]=='.jpg':


                    open(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/static/image/'+name,'wb').write(open(ndir.replace('\\','/')+'/'+name,'rb').read())
                    lis2.append(name)
```

в шаблон передается список картинок,которые пересоздаются из указанной директории в папку /static/image/.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for name in list%}

<img src="{% static "image/{{name}}" %}" alt="My image"/>
{% endfor %}
```

при простом отображении пути к файлам нормально выводятся в список,а при передаче в тег img изображение не отображается а в исходном коде страницы ссылка приобретает вид /static/image/%7B%7Bk%7D%7D

Comment: %7B%7Bk%7D%7D - это, как оказалось, {{name}}.Почему значение не становится на место этой переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for name in list%}

<img src="{% static "image/"|add:name %}" alt="My image"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Потому что в вашем случае вы передаете в качестве аргумента для static строку "image/{{name}}", а не переменную. Поэтому надо склеивать две части строки